Jmeter Json Extractor issue
I am facing an issue in extracting a value for the response and saving it in a variable and using that variable in an other HTTP request but on running the request the fetched Value is not read. but the same thing i have done befor in my project and it is still working perfectly
Json extractor image
HTTP req
Response
I am trying to do stress testing

If JSON Extractor fails to extract the value it means that your JSONPath expression is not correct.
We cannot help you in building a proper expression without seeing at least partial (and better full) response.
So far I can only suggest you to get familiarized with the following materials:

Jayway JsonPath documentation
How to Use the JSON Extractor For Testing

and please don't post JSON response as image, provide it as text
